# Google Extension with more than one button in the toolbar

Tags: button, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a Google Extension that adds 3 buttons to my Google Chrome Toolbar : the Extension does three different things and I want the three buttons to always be available in the toolbar of the user's navigator .. I don't know if it is even possible.

(What I have done so far is a popup that shows three buttons, but it isn't really what I want to do).

Thank you in advance for your precious help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add more than one action to browser with Chrome extension. Chrome extension are meant to [serve single purpose](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/single_purpose) only.

The way you are doing it right now, show popup with three buttons, is the way to do.